# Java: image <-> bytes conversion return null

Tags: java, image, byte, blob, javax.imageio

I'm trying to transfer an image from a client to a server that stocks it into a database. For that, I'm converting my image into a bytes array (it works) and I stock it as blob into the DB (it works).

```
public static byte[] imageToBytes(String path) {
    byte[] imageByte = null;
    File img = new File(path);
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(img);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageByte;
}
```

My problem arrives when I try to read from the DB with the client.

```
public static Image bytesToImage(byte[] bytes) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

The image is null at this point... I searched about it and my code seems to be correct.

I get not only an image from the server, but a whole account with GSon and when I sout my json String I get that:

```
{"username":"Filou","picture":[91,45,49,44,32,45,52,48,44,32,45,49,44,32,45,51,55,44,32,48,44,32,54,55,44,32,48,44,32,56,44,32,54,44,32,54...
```

In order to get the json String from the server, I use a BufferedReader and then I create a User (bean) with it:

```
String strRetour = reader.readLine();
User userReturn = gson.fromJson(strRetour, User.class);
```

In the bean User there is a getter/setter for the picture and when I sout it, it looks fine:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userReturn.getPicture()));
[91, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 52, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 51, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 54, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 56, ...
```

So I guess the bytes array is fine?

My question is: where is the problem? Why is my image null?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem appears to be in the json conversion.  Could you provide the class you're using for serialization?

Comment: I use my reader (reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));) in order to get the json String (User userReturn = gson.fromJson(strRetour, User.class);) and then the getter from my bean User the get the picture. It's a byte array in the bean.

Comment: *So I guess the bytes array is fine?* No, it is not. As you stored it as a JPEG stream, it should start with 255, 216 (SOI). It seems the values are corrupted at some point. Could be when storing in the database (do you store the full 8 bit values?), could be when converting to/from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the bean User there is a getter/setter for the picture and when I sout it, it looks fine:
>
> ```
> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userReturn.getPicture()));
>
> [91, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 52, 48, 44, 32, 45, 49, 44, 32, 45, 51, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 54, 55, 44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 56, ...
> ```
>
> So I guess the bytes array is fine?
>
> My question is: `where is the problem`? Why is my `image null`?

Your shown bytes are not in the JPEG format. Real JPEG data begins with bytes `FF D8`.

```
91 45 49 44 32 45 52 48 44 32 45 49 44 32 45 51         ‘EID2ERHD2EID2EQ
55 44 32 48 44 32 54 55 44 32 48 44 32 56               UD2HD2TUD2HD2V
```

I don't know what format your database/server has converted the jpeg bytes into, but the above is not a known image format (eg: not `.jpg`, or `.png` format etc).

Check the values of `imageByte[0]` and `imageByte[1]` (should `[0]=` **-1** and `[1]=` **-40**), your JSON's image data should match for successful decoding as jpeg.